# Is there an efficient method to compare ndarrays and to keep the nans at their location?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

is there efficient method (in numpy or pandas) to compare ndarray that contains nans with other array, while keeping the nans, instead of replacing them with false?

**Actual behavior:**

`np.array([np.nan]) > 5`  --> `array([False])`,
`pd.Series([np.nan]) > 5`  --> `0    False`

**Desired behavior:**

`np.array([np.nan]) > 5` --> `array([nan])`,
`pd.Series([np.nan]) > 5`  --> `0    NaN`

I know that after the computation it possible to replace the results output with nan according to the input nans' location, but it much less efficient

---

**What I tried:**

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
res = s > 1
res.loc[s.isna()] = np.nan
```

---

- Edited: add solutions below

---

**Fastest solution that were found using Pandas:**

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
res = (s > 1).astype('boolean')
res.loc[s.isna()] = np.nan
```

- Thanks to `@Michael Szczesny`

---

**Fastest solution that were found using NumPy only:**

```
s = pd.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
res = np.where(np.isnan(s), np.nan, s > 1)
```

- Thanks to `@ConfusedReptile | ᓕಲᗣ` (from python discord community)

Comment: Applying comparisons results in arrays of bools. A bool can be True or False. NaN is a float. That's an entirely different type.

Comment: why do you need a logical array to contain nans ? what do you expect to accomplish with a `nan` in a logical array ?

Comment: The included code works with `res = (s > 1).astype('boolean')` using pandas [nullable boolean type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html). But comes with a significant performance penalty.

Comment: For numpy, maybe ```np.sign(a - b)``` would work for you, giving you -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b, 1 if a > b, and NaN if one is NaN. But it would still be a float array, not boolean

Comment: float array is good enough, I just want to drop the nans, so I can get rid of them later.
@ Homer512 I will try your suggestion

Comment: @Michael Szczesny, have you tried your suggestion? it doesn't seem to work...

@Homer512 your suggestion it much faster than what I tried, but it still takes X4 times longer than just the `s>1` computation.

Comment: Yes, I've tried my suggestion and it [works](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z77Iwcmy-isnjycewYGoRfoyICA0i3wY?usp=sharing) if you replace the line in the code you provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, it only does since latter we set the missing locations to np.nan, but without the last line it does not. The problematic line is the last one, which is inefficient.
*edit:* it does improve the `res.loc[s.isna()] = np.nan` running time

Comment: @Michael Szczesny Thanks! your solution is the fastest!